# What does this sed command actually do with those wildcards

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, wildcards

`lineNumber=$(dialog --inputbox "Enter the line number to update that line: " 8 60 --stdout)`

`update=$(dialog --inputbox "Please enter the informations as 'name,surname,phone number,e-mail'" 8 60 --stdout)`

`lineUpdate="${lineNumber}s"`

`sed -i -e "$lineUpdate/.*/$update/" addressbook.csv`

sed -i -e "$lineUpdate/.*/$update/" addressbook.csv

What does the wildcard in sed do?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/706342/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the obvious lack of proper error/invalid input handling from the `dialog` commands which might have a **serious**(unintended substitution/deletion) impact on the expected outcome … this is, however, not the question, but notable nonetheless.

> `sed -i -e "$lineUpdate/.*/$update/" addressbook.csv`
>
> What does the wildcard in sed do?

The option `-e` is not needed in your case ... it's only needed when nesting multiple `sed` scripts like:

```
sed -e 's/orig/new/' -e 's/orig2/new2/' ...
```

`.*` is a regular expression … `.` matches any character (except for line terminators) …  `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) … i.e. `.*` [matches a whole single line](https://regexr.com/6nscd) … so:

```
sed -i "$lineUpdate/.*/$update/" addressbook.csv
```

should substitute the whole line from the `addressbook.csv` file specified by line number passed in `$lineUpdate` asuming something like `3s` in `lineUpdate="${lineNumber}s"`(the `s` here means substitute) with the value passed in `$update` assuming something like `new line` i.e (no errors or unescaped special characters).